# The Infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, conventions, complex-numbers

I am studying Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths. I am kind of stuck on the part of "The infinite square well" where griffith says

> "negative solutions give nothing new, since $\sin(-\omega) = - \sin \omega$ and we can absorb the minus sign into $A$."

To be more specific, he uses boundary conditions on the solution $y(x) = A \sin(kx) + B \cos(kx)$, to show that $B$ is $0$ and $K$ can only take values $\frac{n\pi}{a}$ where $n$ can take values $1,2,3,4$...

My question is:
Since $A$ is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$, how can you "absorb" minus sign into it.

Am i missing something. Please help.

Ps: i couldn't find symbols for psi and theta, so i have used $y$ and $\omega$ in their stead.

Comment: For formatting math, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It means that for negative solutions you have a different value of $A$.  But that "new" solution is identical to the original solution.

Comment: Thanks garyp. I think i understand it now. Since, A^2 = 2/a, it will give 2 values for A, -√(2/a) and +√(2/a).

Comment: not sure what you mean by *boundary conditions on the solution $y(x)=A\sin(kx)+B\sin(kx)$*.  Is this not just $(A+B)\sin(kx)$?

Comment: Ow i am so sorry. It should be Bcos(kx). I will edit it right away. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Griffiths finds that the nontrivial solutions of the stationary Schroedinger equation in the quantum well with infinite barriers at $x=0$ and $x=a$ (where $\psi =0$) are $$\psi(x)=A\sin(k_nx) \tag 1$$ with $$k_n=±n\frac {\pi}{a} \tag 2$$ where $n=1,2,...$ However only the solutions with positive signs for $k_n$ in (2) have to be considered because the solutions with negative $k_n$ are equivalent to the ones with positive sign as the negative sign for $k_n$ in eq. (1) can be taken out of the argument of the sinus and considered to be part of a new arbitrary constant $A'$ so that the solution is the same as the solution with positive $k_n$.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $k,$ which later in the book will be interpreted as momentum, can be either positive or negative.  However, $A\sin(\pm kx)$ is the same as $\pm A\sin(kx)$, which is the same as just $A\sin(kx)$ as long as we don't make any restrictions on $A$'s sign.